# Trouble implementing stores in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

I am trying to create a sveltekit store that will be used to control modals and navigations. Following is the code that I have used in the store

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import { onMount } from 'svelte'

export const store = () => {
    const { subscribe, update } = writable({
        showMenu: false,
        showSubMenu: false,
    });

    onMount(() => {
        // Handle click outside of menu
        const clickOutside = (event: MouseEvent, node: HTMLElement) => {
            if (!node.contains(event.target as Node)) {
                update((storeObject) => {
                    storeObject.showMenu = false;
                    return storeObject;
                })
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener("click", clickOutside);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("click", clickOutside);
        }
    });
}
```

This throws an error 'No operator overload matches this call'. I assume, it is because of the argument of **node** passed inside the clickOutside function.

If this is the case, how can I resolve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to pass a function into `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener` which does not match it. Event handlers only have one argument, the event object and will never be passed a second one.

If anything, the `node` argument should be added to the top level `store` function and thus passed in wherever the store is created.